# DHCP on two Interfaces

Tags: dhcp

Hello i have an Computer with two Interfaces eth1 and wlan0. What happen if i connect my Raspberry pi with a running DHCP on eth1. If a Device on the wlan0 Network request an IP Adresse is this Request answerd by the Raspberry pi in eth1?

Comment: "It depends." Are these wireless and wired networks connected somehow outside of this "Computer" and the "Raspberry pi"? Could you please form the question less abstract: where everything is connected, which addresses it receives, who assigns them and so on?

Comment: by default most unix will not forward tcp connection.